# Android 11: Scoped Storage Permission, how to create new folder in root path of External Storage and SD card Storage?

Tags: android-10.0, file-access, android-11, android-storage

How to get write permission of External Storage of All directories in Android 11, I want to create New Directory or New Folder in the root path of External Storage, I tried with Storage Access Framework and ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent action to request access but not work, SAF Dialog cant not give the root path access in Android 11.

Comment: The user would need to create a directory for you separately, such as via a file manager app. Then, the user can select that directory via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.